# Changing z-index after animation is complete

Tags: jquery

I have a set of divs with position:absolute that I want to animate when the link is clicked. The div should appear to slide out from the bottom to the top and become the top div. (Like putting a card from inside a deck on top.) If I take out the animation, the div will go to the top, but with animation it will not. I know it has to do with the z-index, but I do not know how to set it with the animation.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.card').removeClass('active');
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');

});
```

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#card1 {
  background: blue;
}

#card2 {
  background: red;
}

#card3 {
  background: yellow;
}

#card4 {
  background: green;
}

ul li {
  display: inline
}

.active {
  /* z-index:1;  */
  animation: newCard 2s ease 1;
}

@keyframes newCard {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(400px)
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 999
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#card1">card1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#card2">card2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#card3">card3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#card4">card4</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
<div class='cards'>
  <div id="card1" class="card">1</div>
  <div id="card2" class="card">2</div>
  <div id="card3" class="card">3</div>
  <div id="card4" class="card">4</div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your click function, by binding **animationend** with you card selected.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.card').removeClass('active');
  var id =$(this).attr('href');  
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');
$(id).bind("animationend",function(){$(id).css( "zIndex", 1 );});
});
```

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/j2on20s8/

Comment: With the z-index in .active, I don't get the animation sliding out and in.

Answer (score 0):

Consult this page, you can find out many transitions that can help you: [Transition Article](https://tympanus.net/Development/PageTransitions/)

Or, if you prefer, view the entire article of it: [Page Transition Article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/07/a-collection-of-page-transitions/)

Answer (score 0):

I think wat you may be looking for is to persist the animation change at the end of the keyframe, to do this, add the following property to the `.active` class:

```
.active {
  animation: newCard 2s ease 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Note doing it this way works well, but you will notice that anytime you click on an a link, the last card will pop to the top first before the new card is placed over it. To really have an order to the cards, you'll have to keep a stack of card objects and dynamically change the z-index for each click.

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.card').removeClass('active');
  $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('active');

});
```

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#card1 {
  background: blue;
}

#card2 {
  background: red;
}

#card3 {
  background: yellow;
}

#card4 {
  background: green;
}

ul li {
  display: inline
}

.active {
  animation: newCard 2s ease 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes newCard {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(400px)
  }
  100% {
    z-index: 999
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#card1">card1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#card2">card2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#card3">card3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#card4">card4</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
<div class='cards'>
  <div id="card1" class="card">1</div>
  <div id="card2" class="card">2</div>
  <div id="card3" class="card">3</div>
  <div id="card4" class="card">4</div>
</div>
```